# Eureka-forms Example. How is the Header Font changed

Tags: swift2, format, sample, eureka-forms

I think I've scoured the docs and the sample code up and down. Which admittedly means I'm missing something glaringly obvious.

When I implement Eureka... All my headers are system font, fairly large, Upper and Lower case, and trimmed by elipses.

In the included example project: The sizing, casing, colour, and wrap are all different. I have searched the complete code base for "lineBreakMode" "UIFont" and other such keywords. I have examined the storyboards for odd classes or widgets. Again, nothing stands out.

Any pointers on this would be appreciated as my headers look really poor currently.

Thx!

Comment: quick though, on the example project I did not see any of the header and footer to have a different font or look.

Comment: This situation is comparing the sample to a simple implementation. I haven't changed anything in my app but have vastly different default headers. No Small Caps for example.

Comment: Well Headers and footers have different properties, Headers are all caps by default, and footer have the String's exact Capitalisation

Comment: Interesting, I'm curious why my code _isn't_ giving me all caps. Is there a place in the app that defaults may be getting pulled from?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the Eureka example app to do this :

Create a UIView Class for the header, Add a label to the UIView, configure the label as needed. see here :

```
class NewLabelView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50)
        let label = UILabel(frame: self.frame)
        // setup the label as you wish here
        label.text = "My New Label" // label name
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18) // Font
        label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor() // label textColor
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left // label Alignment
        // end label setup
        self.addSubview(label)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

finally you implement it in your section like this :

```
Section() {
$0.header = HeaderFooterView<NewLabelView>(HeaderFooterProvider.Class)
}
```

after that you modify the frame to make it look as you wish !

Comment: Is there any way to make it re-size (height/width) dynamically depending on the length of the string? How would I do this with 15px margins on left/right and implement in a footer for example?

Comment: implementing on a footer I'm pretty sure would be the same tinhg as the header, just change header to footer, as for dynamic sizing, I'm not sure, I'll do some research and if I find something I'll let you know

Comment: I managed to get dynamic sizing to work. https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/452

Would you happen to know how to pass along the string variable when the class is instantiated in order to avoid hard-coding every section's title string?

Comment: Unfortunatly, I do not. Maybe somebody else could jump in

Comment: Hey @Plastus, if you found my anser helpful, feel free to upvote :)